# Failed to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\28.0.1\lib\dx.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

When I try to run my Android project on Eclipse, these errors appear :

```
[2019-01-28 14:02:47 - Dex Loader] Failed to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\28.0.1\lib\dx.jar
[2019-01-28 14:02:47 - RallisCensus] Unknown error: Unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!
```

Please help to resolve issue.

[Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxiVW.png)

Comment: you likely won't get any help here because there is almost nobody using Eclipse anymore. And soon or later you will have to migrate to Android Studio. The sooner you do the better.